# how to have one array as key and other multiple arrays as values in hashmap perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hashmap

I have the following **arrays**, I need to map the output of `@array2` and `@array3` to the keys of `@array1` in a hash structure.

```
@array1 = ('a', 'b', 'c');
@array2 = (1, 2, 3);
@array3 = ('j', 'k', 'l');
```

Expected output:

```
a => [1, 'j']
b => [2, 'k']
c => [3, 'l']
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example as I am not getting it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over each index of the first array and push what you want into the destination.  Note that the values of `%hash` need to be list-*refs*.

```
$ cat ./foo.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array1 = ( "a", "b", "c" );
my @array2 = ( 1, 2, 3 );
my @array3 = ( "j", "k", "l" );
my %hash;

for( my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@array1); $i++ ){
        push( @{$hash{$array1[$i]}}, $array2[$i], $array3[$i] );
}

print Dumper( \%hash );

$ ./foo.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => [
                   3,
                   'l'
                 ],
          'a' => [
                   1,
                   'j'
                 ],
          'b' => [
                   2,
                   'k'
                 ]
        };
```

Note, for future reference, that it's important to show the SO community that you've made some effort in learning about and solving this yourself (specifically, by showing us what you've tried).  It's likely that, since you didn't do this at all, this question is going to be closed by moderators.

Comment: @neylan it's about giving the correct answer as I have tried to push the elements using references,its not like that I haven't tried.

Comment: my point wasn't that you haven't tried, it's that you didn't *show* us that you've tried.  show your code that didn't work next time.